# Access contents of dynamically generated iframe in Selenium

Tags: iframe, selenium

I want to use XPath (or other Selenium DSL locator) to access a dynamically created `iframe`.  My goal is to make some assertions about the contents of that dynamic iframe.

The `iframe` does not have an ID and has only the following HTML attributes:

```
src="javascript:""" style="position: absolute; left: -2000px;"
```

If I can somehow selectFrame that `iframe`, then I can `assertText` or use XPath to test the `iframe` innards.

However, simple approaches seem to fail.  The `selectFrame("index=0")` fails for some reason.  Perhaps I need some way to `waitFor` the `iframe` to be loaded.  But I can't seem to create the locator identifier for the `iframe`, so I can't `waitFor` it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and can't seem to get it to work. The docs hints don't seem to help, and there isn't much feedback in the logs for the IDE or the Java RC client.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried these tips from Selenium docs?

> SelectFrame ( locator ) Selects a frame within the current window.
>   (You may invoke this command multiple times to select nested frames.)
>   To select the parent frame, use "relative=parent" as a locator; to
>   select the top frame, use "relative=top". You may also use a DOM
>   expression to identify the frame you want directly, like this:
>   dom=frames["main"].frames["subframe"]

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html