# not able to locate an element present in a frame

Tags: java, iframe, selenium-webdriver

element i needed is present in a frame. Code is identifying the frame but not the element present in that frame.

```
<div id="cod-info" class="lightbox infobox">
<div id="returns-info" class="lightbox infobox">
<div id="lb-coupon-widget" class="lightbox">
<div id="lb-login" class="lightbox loginbox loginsignupV2" data-signupsplashpageload="2">
<div id="lightbox-shim" class="lightbox-shim" style="display: block;"></div>
<iframe id="mklogin-iframe" src="javascript:void(0)" name="mklogin-iframe" style="position: absolute; height: 0px; top: -100px;">-----> Frame
<div class="myntra-tooltip">
<div id="lb-sizechart" class="lightbox lb-sizechart" style="display: block;">
<div class="mod" style="min-height: 478px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
<div class="close"></div>
<div class="loading" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="hd">
<div class="bd mk-cf">
<div>
<div id="tab-list" class="mk-f-left lft-cont">
<div class="tab-btns">----> Want to locate element present in this div
Code : driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='mklogin-iframe']")));---- to switch to frame

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='tab-btns']/ul/li)["+2+"]"));---> to locate element.

It is showing unable to locate element
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access contents of dynamically generated iframe in Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321921/access-contents-of-dynamically-generated-iframe-in-selenium)

Comment: Are you sure it's in the iframe? If what you posted is the HTML source then it's not.

Comment: Hi Robin,Actually one i click on one button a new window is opening above the below window and that up window is in frame only.

Comment: I don't think that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not waiting for the element to appear,you can try using [Explicit Wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)...

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("selector_of_element")));
```

Note : *'cssSelector' can be replaced with xpath,id,name,className..etc as per your convinience.*

**OR**

If there are more than one element with the same `selector` or `xpath`,you can try the combination of [Implicit Wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) and `findElements`...

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
List <WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//div[@class='tab-btns']/ul/li)["+2+"]"));
```